# Zenoss auto start off upon system reboot

Tags: zenoss

I have installed Zenoss 5.2.4 on a machine which runs centos 7. I wanted to reboot the machine and thus stopped the `serviced` for graceful shutdown of all the internal services for Zenoss.

Upon rebooting, I see the `serviced` is already running. This shows that the Zenoss.core is started upon system boot time. I want to start the `serviced` and `Zenoss.core` manually after the system reboots. How can I turn on this feature??
 I checked in the `/etc/default/serviced` configuration file but couldn't get any such parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `systemctl disable serviced` before restart and it didn't started up anymore automatically. I enabled and started `serviced` manually.